# Find largest contiguous segment Aritmetic progression

Tags: algorithm, math

- Given A range of integers say A=[a1,a2,a3,a4,...aN] and a common difference 
  D
- I have to find the length largest contiguous segment of numbers in above 
  array that form an arithmetic progression with common difference D.
- Example given A=[2,3,5,7,9,12,14,18] common differnce D=2
- Largest is [3,5,7,9] , length = 4.

First I tried Doing It using brute force check every possible con-sub array for.
But its takinng a long time for large arrays

```py
def ap(test,d):
    l=len(test)
    if l==1:
        return True
    elif l>1:    
        for i in range(l-1):
            if test[i+1]-test[i]!=d:
                return False
                break
        else:
            return True
arr=list(map(int,input().split()))
d=int(input()) # common diff
length=0
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i+1,n+1):
        if ap(arr[i:j],d):
            lon=len(arr[i:j])
            if lon>length:
                length=lon
print(length)
```

Comment: What is the answer for `A=[2,3,5,7,8,9,12,14,18]`? (please, note `8` added) `[3, 5, 7]` or `[3, 5, 7, 9]`?

Comment: Answer for above is [3,5,7,9] we have to find the longest one

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-increasing-consecutive-subsequence/ the only difference is criterium: not just increasing but increasing by given difference

Comment: (I just read through this quickly, but...) if `ap(i, j)` fails is there any point in testing `ap(i, j + 1)`?

Comment: Use dynamic programming. Say let `dp[(i, j)]` be the longest arithmetic sequence starting at `i` with difference `j`. Then we can write the recurrence relationship `dp[(i, arr[i + 1] - arr[i])] = dp[(i + 1, arr[i + 1] - arr[i])] + 1`. By default all `dp[x]` is initialized to one (sequence of just itself).

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-increasing-consecutive-subsequence/  this checks for subsequence mine one ask for largest contingous there should not be breaks. Please explain simply i am new to programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is much simpler then "longest-increasing-consecutive-subsequence" one because 1) you have difference and 2) you need **contiguous** subarray

So it is enough to walk through array once, checking whether current pair of neighbors has needed difference and increment progression length when true

```
for i in range(1, len(A)):
    if A[i]-A[i-1] == d:
         curlen += 1
         maxlen = max(maxlen, curlen)
    else 
         curlen=1
```

Comment: Look at OPs answer to the first comment: it's non-contiguous.

Comment: @Prune I saw this, but title and question body explicitly says about contiguous segment, and author's code also checks contiguous slices. Perhaps author was too hurry when commenting.

Comment: Hmmm ... yes, and the most recent comment also cites "continguous" [sic].

Comment: Can It be made faster than that. Because even O(n) is too much for an array of size 3*10^7. Or if we have to find all multiple arithmetic progression with different common difference.

Comment: O(n) is the fastest possible complexity for given problem  - we **must** check every element. Problem with longest contiguous progression with arbitrary difference has the same complexity (we just check that difference does not change to continue progression and reset it otherwise)